# large column vectors crash in matlab crash win 7 Aero

Tags: windows, matlab, google-chrome, aero

I'm using matlab R2014b 64 bit.  I have a problem with large column or row vectors in matlab, when they get to be the size of about 100K samples or larger.  The software behaves just fine with them, but it's actually the tool-tip that is the problem.

If I hover over the variable, it seems like Aero or DWM crashes under windows 7.  I get sent to a black screen and then it recovers. After it comes back a bunch of my chrome windows are missing their title bars.  I guess it's possible this isn't an Aero problem at all?  Maybe just a chrome thing?  I hope this is the right stack exchange to be asking this question, thanks.

This is what happens:

[image]

Edit:

Save the following code into a .m to reproduced the bug.  Put a breakpoint on the disp() and run the code.  Hover over the variables to generate the crashing tooltip:

```
ok = ones(1,500).*1j;
ok2 = ones(500,1);
notok = ones(500,1).*1j;


disp('done')
```

As seen here, the crash is limited to large complex row formatted variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Run MATLAB as administrator

2) Execute the command `edit datatipinfo` in the MATLAB command prompt

3) On line 48 of the code (might be different in another MATLAB version) which should be `val = val(1:500);`, please reduce the value from 500 to lower number.

4) On line 37 which should be `tooBig = max(s) > 500 || numel(val) > 500;`, please reduce the value to the same number as in step 3

You may have to play around with reducing the value to find something that will work in your case.

from 
https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/43170-viewing-variables-in-debug-window-disables-aero-interface